# Let $f(x)=ax+b$, with $b<a$ both positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Been stuck on this question for some time. I tried solving it via system of equations, using point slope with no luck. What am I missing? I see the line is increasing in the interval $[p,q]$ and this would imply $p<q$ but still not getting anywhere.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two equations tell you
\begin{align}
a p  &= 18 - b,\\
a q & = 39 - b .
\end{align}
So $a$ is a factor of both $18-b$ and $39-b$. Therefore your choices are:

A. $b=1<a \Rightarrow a \text{ is a factor of } 17 \text{ and }38.$

B. $b=3<a \Rightarrow a \text{ is a factor of }  15\text{ and }36$

C. $b=4<a \Rightarrow a \text{ is a factor of }  14\text{ and }35$

D. $b=7<a \Rightarrow a \text{ is a factor of }  11\text{ and }32$

E. $b=8<a \Rightarrow a \text{ is a factor of }  10\text{ and }31$

Only one of these is possible.

Comment: how does $a$ being a factor give you only one choice?

Comment: $a$ being a factor gives you more than one choice, but you also have the condition that $b<a$.

Comment: oope nevermind i got it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the given equations:
$$
18 = ap + b\\
39 = aq + b
$$
Subtract the first equation from the second:
$$
21 = a(q-p)
$$
Integer solutions for $a$ are 3 and 7. If $a=3$ there are no solutions for $b<a$. So $a=7$:
$$
18 = 7p + b\\
39 = 7q + b
$$
Rewritten:
$$
p = \frac{18 - b}{7}\\
q = \frac{39 - b}{7}
$$
Knowing that $p,q$ must be integers try some values of $b<7$.

- $b=1$: $p = \frac{18 - b}{7} = 17/7$, $q = \frac{39 - b}{7} = 38/7$
- $b=2$: $p = \frac{18 - b}{7} = 16/7$, $q = \frac{39 - b}{7} = 37/7$
- $b=3$: $p =\frac{18 - b}{7} = 15/7$, $q = \frac{39 - b}{7} = 36/7$
- $b=4$: $p =\frac{18 - b}{7} = 2$, $q = \frac{39 - b}{7} = 5$

Bingo